# jQuery Function called 2 times on document ready

Tags: jquery

I have that jQuery code:

```
$(function () {

    (function checkWidthOnResize() {
        $(window).on('resize', function () {
            if($(window).width() < 769){
                alert('asdads');
            }
            return false;
        });
    }());

    (function checkWidth() {

        if($(window).width() < 769){
            alert('asddsa');
        }
        return false;
    }());

});
```

When page is ready and I try to resize the screen under `769px`, my first function `checkWidthOnResize()` is loaded two times. In other words I am getting 2 alert messages, one after another.

I would like to understand why this is happening and know how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to jQuery. It depends on the browser when to call the [`window.onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) event. You will get the same result with this code:

```
$(function () {
    window.onresize = function() {
        if($(window).width() < 769) {
            alert('asdads');
        }
    };
});
```

Quote from the [`doc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize):

> Since resize events can fire at a high rate, the event handler
>   shouldn't execute computationally expensive operations such as DOM
>   modifications. Instead, it is recommended to throttle the event using
>   requestAnimationFrame, setTimeout or customEvent, as follows: