# JQuery function call firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to call a function for an html element using jquery. I'm struggling with this has been hours and I can't figure out what is wrong.
I have an answer which I want to mark as solved. A question have multiple answers. 
As far as I know the function is being fired the number of answers I have in the question. If I have two answers, the function will run twice and so on.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $(".accepted.ans").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).closest('.accept');
        console.log(parent);

        var current = $(this);
        console.log(current);
        var url = parent.data('url');
        var qid = parent.data('question');
        var aid = parent.data('answer');

        $.get(url + '?question=' + qid + '&answer=' + aid, function (data) {
            console.log("Reading...");
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(aid);
            console.log(e);
            setAcceptedStatus(current, data.result);
        });
    });

});

function setAcceptedStatus(object, status) {

    if (status === true) {
        object.addClass('active');
    }

}
```

This is my jQuery function. The one that I want to be called exactly once for each answer when I press the `accept ans` div element, which is:

```
<blockquote class="accept-answer text-right {if !$isMine} hidden{/if}" >
    <div class="accept"
         title="Accept this answer"
         data-url="{url('controller/api/questions/mark_as_solved')}"
         data-refresh="{url('controller/api/questions/refresh_accepted_answers')}"
         data-answer="{$answer['answerid']}"
         data-question="{$question['publicationid']}">
        <div class="accepted ans"
             id="{$answer['answerid']}"
             title="Unnacept this answer">
        </div>
    </div>
</blockquote>
```

I thought this was happening because everytime I want to call that function , since I have `$(".accepted.ans")` it will apply to all the `accepted ans` it can find on the document. So I thought in adding an id to the class, something like:

`id="{$answer['answerid']}"`

but as I read somewhere here, it is supposed to work without that.

I really don't know why it triggers more than once, I did all kind of debug, checked the html structure and everything seems flawless.

Any kind soul got an idea in what is wrong?

Regards

Comment: Two things you can try: bind events with "one" instead of "on" and call e.stopPropagation() next to the preventing default

Comment: None of those solutions works.

Comment: Are you sure that the `console.log(parent)` is different for all the times that the event is being fired?

Comment: What is the value of `data-answer` attribute that `console.log(parent)` outputs after each time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Function called 2 times on document ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829086/jquery-function-called-2-times-on-document-ready)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that somehow the `$(document).ready()` function is executed as many times as your answers, so the click event handler is binded the same number of times for each answer. Perhaps it's the template that does that?

If that's indeed the problem and you can't find a solution for the template, try changing
`$(".accepted.ans").on('click', function (e) {`

to

`$(".accepted.ans").off('click').on('click', function (e) {`

to unbind all click event handlers but the last one.

Comment: I agree that this is the likely problem.  Though I would generally recommend correcting it by making sure the onload only happens once.  For example, if the javascript containing the onload is loaded inside of a partial view of some sort then move it to the parent.

Comment: You are the best! I thank you so much @Wizard . Working like a charm!

Comment: Would you care to explain @nurdyguy . You got me curious

Comment: @LuísCosta The issue Wizard described is often called being "multiply bound" or "overly bound".  Basically, because the onload runs more than once the binding is applied more than once.  If the binding is applied 3 times then each click will result in the binding function being run 3 times.  Thus you have two options, 1. fix the problem 2. manage the problem.  What Wizard described is more of a "manage the problem" solution.  To *fix* the problem, make sure the onload only occurs once by rearranging the javascript.  In some cases though you may not have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `.closest(...` to `.parent()`. Snippet below...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".accepted.ans").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var current = $(this),
        parent = current.parent();

    var url = parent.data('url');
    var qid = parent.data('question');
    var aid = parent.data('answer');

    console.log(aid);

    $.get(url + '?question=' + qid + '&answer=' + aid, function(data) {
      console.log("Reading...");
      data = $.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(aid);
      console.log(e);
      setAcceptedStatus(current, data.result);
    });
  });

});

function setAcceptedStatus(object, status) {

    if (status === true) {
        object.addClass('active');
    }

}
```

```css
.ans {
  position: static;
  width: 90%;
  height: 5em;
  background: #f90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<blockquote class="accept-answer text-right {if !$isMine} hidden{/if}">
  <div class="accept" title="Accept this answer" data-url="{url('controller/api/questions/mark_as_solved')}" data-refresh="{url('controller/api/questions/refresh_accepted_answers')}" data-answer="one" data-question="{$question['publicationid']}">
    <div class="accepted ans" id="{$answer['answerid']}" title="Unnacept this answer">
    </div>
  </div>
</blockquote>

<blockquote class="accept-answer text-right {if !$isMine} hidden{/if}">
  <div class="accept" title="Accept this answer" data-url="{url('controller/api/questions/mark_as_solved')}" data-refresh="{url('controller/api/questions/refresh_accepted_answers')}" data-answer="two" data-question="{$question['publicationid']}">
    <div class="accepted ans" id="{$answer['answerid']}" title="Unnacept this answer">
    </div>
  </div>
</blockquote>

<blockquote class="accept-answer text-right {if !$isMine} hidden{/if}">
  <div class="accept" title="Accept this answer" data-url="{url('controller/api/questions/mark_as_solved')}" data-refresh="{url('controller/api/questions/refresh_accepted_answers')}" data-answer="three" data-question="{$question['publicationid']}">
    <div class="accepted ans" id="{$answer['answerid']}" title="Unnacept this answer">
    </div>
  </div>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: ...though I'm noting that the snippet above works with closest also, so the cause of your problem might lie elsewhere? possibly the js script is being run twice?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you need to prevent it's function listened by other event attached to its parental tags. So try the `stopPropagation();` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$(".accepted.ans").on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).closest('.accept');
    console.log(parent);

    var current = $(this);
    console.log(current);
    var url = parent.data('url');
    var qid = parent.data('question');
    var aid = parent.data('answer');

    $.get(url + '?question=' + qid + '&answer=' + aid, function (data) {
        console.log("Reading...");
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(aid);
        console.log(e);
        setAcceptedStatus(current, data.result);
    });
});

});

function setAcceptedStatus(object, status) {

if (status === true) {
    object.addClass('active');
}

}
```